# Not able to run mysql 8.0.12 as root on macOS

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded macOS 10.13 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive and install it on my Mac(10.13.6) but while accessing it in terminal it's not taking root password which I have set during the installation process.

I have checked system preference MySQL is running and trying to access MySQL by below command, though it's asking for the password but not taking it after trying it, its giving below error

sudo /user/local/mysql -u root -p

error : sudo: /user/local/mysql: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install `mysql` there. Double-check where it's actually installed. You'll probably be able to use plain old `mysql` as the command name.

Comment: have tried but it's not working. basic directory on my Mac is /usr/local/mysql

Comment: Then `mysql` will be inside it. Write `/usr/local/mysql/mysql`.